# How can I get value from radio and alert checked value?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-5

I made a radio input type.
When I check radio 1, input text 1 appears.
When I check radio 2, input text 2 will show.
When I check radio 3, input text 3 will appear.

and i will get value from checked input

thank you in advance

```js
check1 = document.getElementById("check-me");
check2 = document.getElementById("check-other");
check3 = document.getElementById("check-emp");

if (check1.checked) {
  name = document.getElementById("send1");
}
elseif(check2.checked) {
  name = document.getElementById("send2");
}
elseif(check3.checked) {
  name = document.getElementById("send3");
}

//alert when input is blank
if (name == null || name == "") {
  alert("your input is blank!");
}
```

```html
<input class="form-check-input" type="radio" id="check-me" name="chooseReq" checked>
<input class="form-check-input" type="radio" id="check-other" name="chooseReq">
<input class="form-check-input" type="radio" id="check-emp" name="chooseReq">

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="send1" name="send1">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="send2" name="send2">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="send3" name="send3">
```

Comment: and where is your js?

Comment: Im Sorry. I forgot to mention that the result is Javascript

Comment: Java is not the same as Javascript and you are supposed to post all your relevant code and your attempt

Comment: you have to give more details tho, what event is supposed to trigger your alert? Im guessing that happens in an onblur event of your inputs?

Comment: You have syntax problems (`elseif`) and you're not checking values or checked state. You're just getting elements.

Comment: if you fix what @isherwood mentioned your code still has problems, the alert pops up on page load only once and then what? no other event is triggering your alert and there is nothing in your code that will return the value that you want

Comment: when detected The input text selected by radio input is empty.

Comment: it will always be empty on page load so will always have that alert poping up once and then nothing

Comment: @isherwood What should I do is `elseif(check3.checked == true)`  ,right?

Comment: @ChrisG I just need a popup on null to check for null from the input selected by the radio input. But the problem is that when I select another radio input and its value is blank, there is no alert when submit.

Comment: You don't need to check for true explicitly, and `elseif` isn't a thing in JavaScript. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else#description

Comment: Thank you to everyone; it took me hours to find the solution; I forgot to put the.value after the document. getElementById(), so null was not found.